# java.lang.System.setProperty(): security issue on my server?

Tags: java, security

I have created a client-server Java program.

The user can specify any argument for this following method server-side:

```
 java.lang.System.setProperty(String key, String value)
```

The user's input is sent to the server and this one is put as arguments of this previous method.

The user controls both **key** and **value** server-side.

I don't want the user can execute system commands on the server for example.

- Do you know if a user specifies malicious arguments to this method, he can escape from the Java process server-side?
- Do you know if he can execute system commands on my server thanks to this Java method for example? How can he do that? I have read JAVA documentation, and there is not "cmd" like JAVA properties.

Comment: Why not limit the user's possible actions if you are worried about security? Maybe let the user choose the keys and values from a combo box?

Comment: Yes this is a security issue. Yes this is a terrible idea. Yes you should nuke it from orbit. As a simple example, what if the user sets `user.home` to something else?

Comment: Why would any user have to set system properties of a remote Java program? A user shouldn't even care whether the application he/she uses is written in Java or not. And there is no reason for you to let the user mess with system properties. Why would you do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: About 'user.home' property, I don't understand how the user should be able to escape from JVM on my server. He will not able to modify a file or to execute a system command. Do you have more information about security risks ?

Comment: The JVM will modify files for you and execute things if you point it at them. For example, you are allowing the user to fiddle with the classpath. Furthermore, how do you know one of your libraries doesn't use system properties for such things - case in point, Logback will execute Groovy scripts as configuration.

Comment: I don't know what else the user can trigger. Depending on that, the user can misuse some property to gain access.